# Running Python script through command, Syntax Error

Tags: python-2.7, terminal, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I use a Raspberry Pi 3, and I'm trying to run this Python script through the command terminal:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

Motor1A = 16
Motor1B = 18
Motor1E = 22

GPIO.setup(Motor1A,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(Motor1B,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(Motor1E,GPIO.OUT)

print "Turning motor on"
GPIO.output(Motor1A,GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.output(Motor1B,GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(Motor1E,GPIO.HIGH)

sleep(2)

print "Stopping motor"
GPIO.output(Motor1E,GPIO.LOW)

GPIO.cleanup()
```

The file is called "motor1.py". It is located in the "/home/pi" directory.

When I type `sudo python motor1.py`, the terminal responds like so:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo python motor1.py
    File "motor.py", line 1
      Python 2.7.9 (default, Sep 17 2016, 20:26:04)
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can anyone tell me why? Thank a lot.

Johnny

Comment: Thanks a lot for the edit, Mr. Valencia.

Comment: You're welcome. Also, is it `motor1.py` or `motor.py`?

Comment: Yeah, I saw my other error. It's motor1.py.

Comment: By any chance, did you use IDLE to create and save your script?

Comment: Yes, I did use IDLE on a raspberry Pi 3.

Comment: That might be the problem. I'll write an answer and see if that works.

Comment: I guess the problem is not what I thought it was. Sorry I was not able to help. I will delete my answer, but maybe you'll find something useful here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=96174

Comment: What other files are in the directory?  And to that note, it would behoove you to create a directory specific for this project.  Putting it in home is asking for all sorts of challenges.